# how to recognize specific pattern and paste it over a section

Tags: bash

I have a huge data txt file like the following and I want to convert it to a format that I can easily look into it. I have tried to search for ID

I tried to use *command | sed -n 'ID'* but it only tries to find the ID so I really cannot figure out how to make the following format

```
    //
    ID   1.1.1.1
    DE   Alcohol dehydrogenase.
    AN   Aldehyde reductase.
    CA   (1) A primary alcohol + NAD(+) = an aldehyde + NADH.
    CA   (2) A secondary alcohol + NAD(+) = a ketone + NADH.
    CF   Zn(2+) or Fe cation.
    CC   -!- Acts on primary or secondary alcohols or hemi-acetals with very broad
    CC       specificity; however the enzyme oxidizes methanol much more poorly
    CC       than ethanol.
    CC   -!- The animal, but not the yeast, enzyme acts also on cyclic secondary
    CC       alcohols.
    PR   PROSITE; PDOC00058;
    PR   PROSITE; PDOC00059;
    PR   PROSITE; PDOC00060;
    DR   P07327, ADH1A_HUMAN;  P28469, ADH1A_MACMU;  Q5RBP7, ADH1A_PONAB;
    DR   P25405, ADH1A_SAAHA;  P00325, ADH1B_HUMAN;  Q5R1W2, ADH1B_PANTR;
    DR   P14139, ADH1B_PAPHA;  P25406, ADH1B_SAAHA;  P00327, ADH1E_HORSE;
    DR   P00326, ADH1G_HUMAN;  O97959, ADH1G_PAPHA;  P00328, ADH1S_HORSE;
    //
    ID   1.1.1.2
    DE   Alcohol dehydrogenase (NADP(+)).
    AN   Aldehyde reductase (NADPH).
    CA   An alcohol + NADP(+) = an aldehyde + NADPH.
    CF   Zn(2+).
    CC   -!- Some members of this group oxidize only primary alcohols; others act
    CC       also on secondary alcohols.
    CC   -!- May be identical with EC 1.1.1.19, EC 1.1.1.33 and EC 1.1.1.55.
    CC   -!- Re-specific with respect to NADPH.
    PR   PROSITE; PDOC00061;
    DR   Q6AZW2, A1A1A_DANRE;  Q568L5, A1A1B_DANRE;  Q24857, ADH3_ENTHI ;
    DR   Q04894, ADH6_YEAST ;  P25377, ADH7_YEAST ;  O57380, ADH8_PELPE ;
    DR   Q9F282, ADHA_THEET ;  P0CH36, ADHC1_MYCS2;  P0CH37, ADHC2_MYCS2;
    DR   P0A4X1, ADHC_MYCBO ;  P9WQC4, ADHC_MYCTO ;  P9WQC5, ADHC_MYCTU ;
    DR   P27250, AHR_ECOLI  ;  Q3ZCJ2, AK1A1_BOVIN;  Q5ZK84, AK1A1_CHICK;
    DR   O70473, AK1A1_CRIGR;  P14550, AK1A1_HUMAN;  Q9JII6, AK1A1_MOUSE;
    DR   P50578, AK1A1_PIG  ;  Q5R5D5, AK1A1_PONAB;  P51635, AK1A1_RAT  ;
    DR   Q6GMC7, AK1A1_XENLA;  Q28FD1, AK1A1_XENTR;  Q9UUN9, ALD2_SPOSA ;
    DR   P27800, ALDX_SPOSA ;  P75691, YAHK_ECOLI ;
```

I want to pick up ID at the top of each section and then paste it in front of each protein name. they are separated with a ; from one another

so the output would look like

```
PR   PROSITE;               1.1.1.1
PR   PDOC00058;             1.1.1.1
PR   PROSITE;               1.1.1.1
PR   PDOC00059;             1.1.1.1
DR   P07327, ADH1A_HUMAN;   1.1.1.1
DR   P28469, ADH1A_MACMU;   1.1.1.1
DR   Q5RBP7, ADH1A_PONAB;   1.1.1.1
DR   P25405, ADH1A_SAAHA;   1.1.1.1
DR   P00325, ADH1B_HUMAN;   1.1.1.1
DR   Q5R1W2, ADH1B_PANTR;   1.1.1.1
DR   P14139, ADH1B_PAPHA;   1.1.1.1
DR   P25406, ADH1B_SAAHA;   1.1.1.1
DR   P00327, ADH1E_HORSE;   1.1.1.1
DR   P00326, ADH1G_HUMAN;   1.1.1.1
DR   O97959, ADH1G_PAPHA;   1.1.1.1
DR   P00328, ADH1S_HORSE;   1.1.1.1
PR   PROSITE;               1.1.1.2
PR   PDOC00061;             1.1.1.2
DR   Q6AZW2, A1A1A_DANRE;   1.1.1.2
DR   Q568L5, A1A1B_DANRE;   1.1.1.2
DR   Q24857, ADH3_ENTHI ;   1.1.1.2
DR   Q04894, ADH6_YEAST ;   1.1.1.2
DR   P25377, ADH7_YEAST ;   1.1.1.2
DR   O57380, ADH8_PELPE ;   1.1.1.2
DR   Q9F282, ADHA_THEET ;   1.1.1.2
DR   P0CH36, ADHC1_MYCS2;   1.1.1.2
DR   P0CH37, ADHC2_MYCS2;   1.1.1.2
DR   P0A4X1, ADHC_MYCBO ;   1.1.1.2
DR   P9WQC4, ADHC_MYCTO ;   1.1.1.2
DR   P9WQC5, ADHC_MYCTU ;   1.1.1.2
DR   P27250, AHR_ECOLI  ;   1.1.1.2
DR   Q3ZCJ2, AK1A1_BOVIN;   1.1.1.2
DR   Q5ZK84, AK1A1_CHICK;   1.1.1.2
DR   O70473, AK1A1_CRIGR;   1.1.1.2
DR   P14550, AK1A1_HUMAN;   1.1.1.2
DR   Q9JII6, AK1A1_MOUSE;   1.1.1.2
DR   P50578, AK1A1_PIG  ;   1.1.1.2
DR   Q5R5D5, AK1A1_PONAB;   1.1.1.2
DR   P51635, AK1A1_RAT  ;   1.1.1.2
DR   Q6GMC7, AK1A1_XENLA;   1.1.1.2
DR   Q28FD1, AK1A1_XENTR;   1.1.1.2
DR   Q9UUN9, ALD2_SPOSA ;   1.1.1.2
DR   P27800, ALDX_SPOSA ;   1.1.1.2
DR   P75691, YAHK_ECOLI ;   1.1.1.2
```

Comment: This looks doable, but big. Use `awk`, store the "section header" (ie. 1.1.1.2 or 1.1.1.1) then go through the lines and from the lines starting with PR and DR extract the strings before `;`. A bit of work. What have you tried?

Comment: @Kamil Cuk I cannot figure out the second part you wrote

Comment: If a line starts with PR or DR, then split the line on `;`, then for each string splitted print the output.

Comment: @ Kamil Cuk if I want to do `awk` where am I doing wrong ? `awk '$1="ID"{print $0}' df.txt` I call the text file as df.txt

Comment: You can find many tutorials online how to use `awk`. You are doing nothing wrong, just.. not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm sure it's possible with `awk`, I'd use `perl` for this, because I know it better:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
use vars qw/$id/;

# save the id to use later
if (/^\s*id\s+(.*?)$/i) {
  $id = $1;
}

# when we see a PR or DR line, save the interesting bits
if (/^\s*([pd]r)\s+((?:[^;]+;\s*)+)/i) {
  my ($type, $labels) = ($1, $2);
  # split it on semis
  for my $label (split(/;\s*/, $labels)) {
    # and output the desired format
    printf("%s\t%s;\t%s\n", $type, $label, $id)
  }
}
```

Calling it like so:

```
./tx in.txt > gen.txt
```

gives the expected output, plus two lines from `PDOC00060`:

```
$ diff -bwiu gen.txt expected.txt
--- gen.txt     2019-01-09 10:06:59.000000000 -0700
+++ expected.txt        2019-01-09 09:58:32.000000000 -0700
@@ -2,8 +2,6 @@
 PR     PDOC00058;      1.1.1.1
 PR     PROSITE;        1.1.1.1
 PR     PDOC00059;      1.1.1.1
-PR     PROSITE;        1.1.1.1
-PR     PDOC00060;      1.1.1.1
 DR     P07327, ADH1A_HUMAN;    1.1.1.1
 DR     P28469, ADH1A_MACMU;    1.1.1.1
 DR     Q5RBP7, ADH1A_PONAB;    1.1.1.1
```

Comment: I like your answer and I want to accept it, I have a question, what if I want to pick up only the first part of the section like I mentioned above

Comment: You don't need anything fancy for that, assuming I'm understanding correctly, an `egrep` should suffice: `egrep -iv '^\s*[dp]r' in.txt` to strip out all the lines beginning with `DR` or `PR`